# Checking for a record in a Database before deleting using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures, ado.net

This is my Web API code for deleting a record using ADO.NET.

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
public PeopleAPIController(IConfiguration configuration)
{
   _configuration = configuration;
}

[HttpDelete]
public IActionResult DeletePeople(int id)
{
    string connectionString = _configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
    using(SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spDeletePeople", connection);
                
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tnId", id);
                
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();          
    }
    return Ok("deleted");
}
```

How can I check whether the record is existing or  not?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that this is your People table schema

```
CREATE TABLE People
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    -- Other properties
)
```

Work with the [`ExecuteScalar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#remarks) method to query if there is a record with the respective ID. If the ID does not exist (count = 0), return `NotFound()` response. Otherwise, proceed to execute the stored procedure for the deletion.

```
string connectionString = _configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM People WHERE ID = @id", connection);
                
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (count == 0)
        return NotFound();

    /* Execute Stored Procedure for DELETE action */
}
```

Comment: I will  work with this also. I didn't include COUNT in my stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want to do this. If you want to delete it then there is no need to check if exists. Delete will remove it if exists and there is no error if it doesn't exist.

However [ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#returns) returns an integer that is the number of records affected by the command. So, unless your Stored Procedure contains the instruction

[SET NOCOUNT ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

you should simply get the result from ExecuteNonQuery

```
int recordsDeleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If the value is 1 then the record was present and it has been deleted.

Comment: I wanted to check whether we can delete a record that's not there.  Anyway I'll check this out.

Comment: OK, but still, if your objective is to delete the record anyway, you just read the result from ExecuteNonQuery and give the warning to your user if the result is zero.

Comment: Yes i will do that.